# Run UPDATE query for every row in another SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL Query that can return from 0 to let's say 20 results. Here is for example:

```
SELECT value_id FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON ....
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON ....
WHERE ....
```

Then, I want to run for each `value_id` an UPDATE query. Let's say:

```
UPDATE table4

SET new_value = 1

WHERE value_id IN (SELECT value_id FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON ....
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON ....
WHERE ....)
```

Can a subquery work on this? Is it performance efficient or there is another way?

Comment: Hi @utility. It is MSSQL

Comment: update using joins are better than the subquery

Comment: Yes there is another way. You can use join (Update From) or use template table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is fine.  The performance depends on how your database is structured.  For instance, if the `SELECT` runs fast, then the `UPDATE` should be pretty fast (not as fast: there is more overhead for the `UPDATE`).

So, the answer to your question is:  Yes, a subquery can work like this.  Test the `SELECT` version (with `table4`) to get an idea of the affect on performance.